# Observe mutable live data of a data class's property changes

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-livedata

In [Android Kotlin Fundamentals](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/kotlin-android-training-live-data/#5), the code mentions of using a backing property to encapsulate the `MutableLiveData` in `ViewModel` so that only the `ViewModel` itself can change said mutable value. Different from the practice, I'm using a data class instead. I would like to observe the changes to the property of the data class and display it in the UI.

Here's what I have so far.

```
class CourseViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private var _lastAccessedCourse: MutableLiveData<Course>
    val lastAccessedCourse: LiveData<Course>
        get() = _lastAccessedCourse
    // Some other code...

    fun updateProgress() {
        if (_lastAccessedCourse.value != null)
            _lastAccessedCourse.value = _lastAccessedCourse.value!!.let {
                it.progress += 5
                it
            }
    }
```

Then, I will observe the `lastAccessedCourse` in my UI like below. A button click updates the variable `progress` and that change is what I am observing.

```
binding.fragHomeLaReadButton.setOnClickListener {
    courseViewModel.updateProgress()
}

courseViewModel.lastAccessedCourse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
    binding.fragHomeLaProgress.progress = it.progress
})
```

My data class is simple.

```
data class Course(
    var name: String,
    var category: String,
    var progress: Int
)
```

This works. However, I have a concern. When I tried to `updateProgress()` without setting `_lastAccessedCourse` variable (and instead just adding `5` to progress), it seems like the change isn't observed. I suspect that this is because it doesn't observe the data class's property changes. Is this correct?

As can be seen, I'm returning a new `Course` to `_lastAccessedCourse` variable every time I call `updateProgress()`. Does this have a performance drawback? Is there a better practice to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `MutableLiveData` only notifies its observers if the `value` is changed. Changes to the class (`Course` in your case) are not observed.

For best practice, consider using an immutable data class for `Course` and assigning a new one to the `LiveData` each time:

```
data class Course(
    val name: String,
    val category: String,
    val progress: Int
)

val course = /* TODO: get current course */
val newCourse = course.copy(progress = course.progress + 5)
_lastAccessedCourse.value = newCourse
```

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as what I did?

Comment: Basically yes, but you asked for best practice.

Comment: Ah okay. I've reread your answer, yours differ from mine as your data class is immutable.