# Android Mutablelivedata list item didn't notify changed

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mutablelivedata

I declared variable like this.

```
var saleData: MutableLiveData<SaleData> = MutableLiveData()
```

**data class**

```
data class SaleData(
    var saleType: Int,
    var saleDetail: Int,
    var salePrice: Int,
    var saleRate: Int,
    var printAmount: Int
)
```

and then, init the data

```
init {
 saleData.value = SaleData(saleType = 1, saleDetail = 0, salePrice = 0, saleRate = 0, printAmount = 1)
}
```

The question is, if one of the components of the data class in SaleData changes, can I be notified of this?
I simply wrote the code as below, but there was no result value.

**viewModel**

```
fun changeData() {
    saleData.value?.saleRate = 50
}
```

fragment - at onCreateView

```
binding.viewModel = viewModel
binding.lifecycleOwner = this
viewModel.saleData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { saleData ->
    Log.d(TAG,"value changed")
})
```

I can't get the Log when change the saleRate in saleData

Like this code,

```
saleData.value = SaleData(saleType = saleType, saleDetail = 0, salePrice = 0, saleRate = 0, printAmount = 1)
```

I set saleData value, it notify the value changed but I want when change the item of saleData, notify the change

Is there anything else I need to set up?

Comment: Possible dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61192563/observe-mutable-live-data-of-a-data-classs-property-changes

Comment: It might be not working because the reference to the saleData didnt change. You can also try to call saleData.postValue(...) and see if it changes anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A call to `saleData.value?.saleRate = 50` will not notify observers because the underlying object stored within the `MutableLiveData` remains unchaged. For `LiveData` to notify its observers, you need to assign a new object to it.
Assuming `SaleData` is a data class, you can make it notify it's observers by calling,

`saleData.value  = saleData.value?.copy(saleRate = 50)`

This will notify all registered observers.

Comment: I didn't know I was supposed to do that. I thought I'd get a notification if I just changed one component, but it wasn't. Thank you for your reply. You save my time :)

Answer (score 1):

As [Rafsanjani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5430306/rafsanjani) said, you need to assign an updated reference of the SaleData class to the LiveData. Once you do that, the LiveData observer will notify the changes. For better understanding, please, see the code below.

**SaleDataViewModel**

```
class SaleDataViewModel: ViewModel() {
   private var _saleData: MutableLiveData<SaleData> = MutableLiveData()
   val saleData: LiveData<SaleData> = _saleData

   init {
      _saleData.value = SaleData(saleType = 1, saleDetail = 0, salePrice = 0, saleRate = 0, printAmount = 1)
   }

   fun updateSale() {
      val saleRate = updatedSaleRate()
      _saleData.value = SaleData( _saleData.value!!.saleType, _saleData.value!!.saleDetail, _saleData.value!!.salePrice, saleRate, _saleData.value!!.printAmount)
   }

   private fun updatedSaleRate(): Int {
      return 50
   }
}
```

**SaleDataFragment**

```
class SaleDataFragment: Fragment() {
   ...
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState) {
     viewModel.updateSale()
     viewModel.saleData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
         Log.d(TAG, "Notify change")
     })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation with the detailed code. I'll use it well.